# wrong ylim in R

Tags: r, plot, label, axis

I have 2 problems with r plot function:

1. When I try to plot this (example below), there is always a -1 value on y axis despite of I set ylim to c(0,max(...)*1.5). How can I set the ylim value to 0?
2. My second problem is that I would like to round the y axis labels (0 decimal). I know that I can do it manually:  (axis(side = 2, at=seq(1,3,1), labels = c(-1,0,1))). But i would like a "universe" solution because I'll make many plots with for loop with different axis.

## example:

```
xy = c(NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,0,0)

plot(xy, ylim = c(0,max(c(NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,0,0),na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is because your code is equivalent to `ylim=c(0,0)`. What do you expect the plot to look like? If the specified range in y (or x) is 0, `plot(...)` reverts to default algorithm for calculating axis limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in your question 1 is that defining

```
ylim = c(0,max(c(NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,NA,0,0),na.rm = TRUE))
```

is equal to

```
ylim = c(0,0)
```

even if you multiply the second 0 by any positive number. So you are telling R to make the y-axis from 0 to 0 and I believe R understands that that doesn't make sense and therefore makes a kind of default ylim from -1 to 1.

To avoid that, you could add a positive number, e.g. 1, instead of multiplying it so your code would be, for example:

```
plot(xy, ylim = c(0,max(xy,na.rm = TRUE)+1))
```

Comment: Ohh, what a silly I am... :) Thanks for Your reply! 

Could You answer my second answer also?

Comment: I think that depends on the data. For the example you provided, I don't see any sense in rounding the y-axis labels to 0 decimals. It would rather make sense to define the sequence of axis ticks as you already did in your question.

Comment: Yes, but it is difficult to define it, because I'll make 100+ graphs with for loop and each plot has a different y axis lengths.

Comment: You need to define a new plotting function that calls `plot` but suppresses t-axis and then labels your y-axis with rounded values over the range of values in the data. I suspect you want to use floor() and ceil() as your "rounding" functions for the ylim

Comment: Maybe i was not totally clear: I only want to show the rounded up values (in my example, only 0 and 1). So how can I hide 1,5 and 0,5?

Comment: Thanks @BondedDust for the expert input. Unfortunately I couldn't easily define such a new plotting function, so I can't help with that one. I still wonder if this kind of axis label modification is really "a good idea" or even necessary, since - provided the data range is larger than in the example - the y-axis will usually default to integer values and not show any decimals.

Comment: @user3679113: I thought the request was clear enough and I thought the strategy would need at a minimum to extend the values of ylim to cover the "integerization" that you wanted. You would then need to use `as.integer(yvar_range)` for your 'at' argument, and the same argument to labels.

Comment: Yes I've had a same train of thought. Anybody knows the default algorithm of 'at' and 'labels'? If we know that, we just have to complete with as.interger("algorithm") or round("algorithm",0)